# Adding additional jQuery UI behavior to Joomla 3

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3 for a project and am happy that they added jQuery to the CMS. The "approved" way to add jQuery UI support is by adding `JHtml::_('jquery.ui');` to the head of your document.

However, they only support a minimal set of widgets. If I want to use a non-standard widget like 'Progress Bar' for example, how can I add this without adding (redundantly) the required jQuery core elements that come with the jQuery downloader?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by downloading the older version of jQuery UI included with Joomla (at the time of this post, it is 1.8.23) rather than using the "builder" on the jQuery UI site. jQuery 1.8.23 can be found here:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/downloads/detail?name=jquery-ui-1.8.23.zip&can=2&q=

Then, use the `JHtml::('jquery.ui')` call to load the core of the jQuery UI, and just include the actual widget code you need from the download link above. This seems to work well and not conflict with other components / plugins / templates that may also load jQuery UI using the Joomla API.

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); // load jquery
JHtml::_('jquery.ui'); // load jquery ui from Joomla
$this->document->addScript(JURI::root(true).'/components/com_mycomponent/assets/jquery.ui.slider.min.js'); // load *same version* widget code from jQuery UI archive
```

Comment: This will also break another extension if it loads the slider too :-)

Comment: @Laoneo- true! But until Joomla improves their API, this is about as good a workaround as I could find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JUX libraries include the core jQuery UI code plus Widget, Mouse, Position, and Sortable (version 1.8.23 as of Joomla 3.0.2). Please review the jQuery-UI documentation for further details on their usage.

In order to load the core call: `JHtml::_('jquery.ui');`

This will load the appropriate jquery-ui.core.js from the media/jui directory. Enabling jQuery UI automatically enables jQuery in noConflict mode if it has not already been done.

To add the Sortable library, use `JHtml::_('jquery.ui', array('sortable'));` This will automatically include the core jQuery UI library and the jQuery library.

For clarity, it is best to explicitly enable both the core and sortable from a single call using `JHtml::_('jquery.ui', array('core', 'sortable'));`

As of Joomla 3.0.2, only jQuery UI Core and Sortable are installed/available. To use other jQuery plugins, including jQuery UI plugins, you will need to make sure they are installed with your application and call JHtml::_('script') along with the appropriate parameters to load them. Alternatively, you may create and install your own JHtml extensions and create your own JHtml calls - such as `JHtml::_('mylibrary.myloader')`

You can see more from [this](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) page

Answer (score 0):

You can build your custom jQuery UI from the download page http://jqueryui.com/download with the widgets you need extra. Afterwards you can modify the downloaded javascript files by removing the parts which come with Joomla core already. There is no way around it, except that you don't load `JHtml::_('jquery.ui');` at all.

I would also be more than happy when Joomla would come with a more advanced solution to load jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks Laoneo, however this breaks when another plugin / template / module also requires the jQuery UI.

Comment: My proposed solution is exactly like your own answer that you have to load an extra file with the widgets you need. Most users install jQuery easy (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327). Which comes with built in jQuery UI support and cleans up the site with duplicate scripts (with some magic regex replace commands).